# Flutter: How to make scroll of each Column widget in the Wrap widget?

Tags: flutter

ex:

```
  final w1 = Text('w1');
  final w2 = Text('w2');
  final c1 = Container(color: Colors.cyan, width: 500, child: Column(children: [for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) Text('c1: $i')]));
  final c2 = Container(color: Colors.brown, width: 500, child: Column(children: [for (int i = 100; i > 0; i--) Text('c2: $i')]));
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        w1,
        w2,
        Wrap(
          children: [
            c1,
            c2,
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

It works fine when the screen is lower than the width of these items.
But when it's not, I want to separate the scroll bar of c1 and c2.
Can I do this without using a responsive widget like `LayoutBuilder` or using the height fixing of other items (w1 and w2)?

I tried to wrap the `SingleChildScrollView` of each item in the `Wrap`, but it did not help.

```
  final w1 = Text('w1');
  final w2 = Text('w2');
  final c1 = Container(color: Colors.cyan, width: 500, child: Column(children: [for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) Text('c1: $i')]));
  final c2 = Container(color: Colors.brown, width: 500, child: Column(children: [for (int i = 100; i > 0; i--) Text('c2: $i')]));
  return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          w1,
          w2,
          Container(color: Colors.orange, height: 100, width: double.infinity),
          Wrap(
            children: [
              SingleChildScrollView(child: c1),
              SingleChildScrollView(child: c2),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Can we make this without using the responsive like `LayoutBuilder` or widget height fixing?
I don't want to interfere with the other widget these outsides of the `Wrap` (in this case w1 and w2) like this example below. I need to write the whole page 2 times and interfere with the w1 and w2 widgets and this doesn't use the `Wrap` widget. I expect to do this below by just using the `Wrap` + `SingleChildScrollView` widgets.

```
  final w1 = Text('w1');
  final w2 = Text('w2');
  final c1 = Container(color: Colors.cyan, width: 500, child: Column(children: [for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) Text('c1: $i')]));
  final c2 = Container(color: Colors.brown, width: 500, child: Column(children: [for (int i = 100; i > 0; i--) Text('c2: $i')]));
  return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          if (constraints.maxWidth < 750) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  w1,
                  w2,
                  Container(color: Colors.orange, height: 100, width: double.infinity),
                  c1,
                  c2,
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
          return Column(
            children: [
              w1,
              w2,
              Container(color: Colors.orange, height: 100, width: double.infinity),
              Expanded(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    SingleChildScrollView(child: c1),
                    SingleChildScrollView(child: c2),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want each column in the Wrap widget to have its own scrolling functionality, you can wrap each column with a SingleChildScrollView widget

Wrap(
  children: [
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          w1,
          w2,
        ],
      ),
    ),
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          c1,
          c2,
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: This isn't what I want.
I want to use `Wrap` with c1 and c2, not w1/w2 and c1/c2.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `SingleChildScrollView` into `Container` with `fixed height`.

So, your code will be like below:

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        w1,
        w2,
        Expanded(
          child: Wrap(
            children: [
                 Container(
                    height: 100,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(child: c1),
                    ),
                  ),
                 Container(
                    height: 100,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(child: c1),
                    ),
                  ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

**UPDATE**

another way to achieve this, for
`auto-change the c1 and c2 from horizontal to vertical when the width of the screen is lower than the sum of the width of c1 and c2`

Make new `function` that `return widget`.

```
Widget myWidget(BuildContext context){
  List<Widget> _list = [];
  _list.add(Expanded(child: SingleChildScrollView(child: c1)));
  _list.add(Expanded(child: SingleChildScrollView(child: c2)));
  if(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 750){ //sum of the width of c1 and c2
    return Column(children: _list);
  }else{
    return Row(children: _list);
  }
}
```

then call them like:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            w1,
            w2,
            Container(color: Colors.orange, height: 100, width: double.infinity),
            Expanded(
              child: myWidget(context),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I don't want to fix the height of my item.
But I knew this is the last solution that I will do.

Comment: Use  `Row` OR `Column` instead of `Wrap`, And put into `Expanded`. Then put every `SingleChildScrollView` into `Expanded`.

Comment: I use `Wrap` to auto-change the c1 and c2 from horizontal to vertical when the width of the screen is lower than the sum of the width of c1 and c2.

Comment: another way to achieve this, see my `update answer`

Comment: Thank you for a good trick.
But I want to use the `Wrap` widget to make this UI in one step and don't need to calculate the size of the widget or screen(the `Wrap` widget already does this). At the moment I do that similar to you by using `LayoutBuilder`. Maybe the `Wrap` widget can't do this at the moment or can do this but I don't l know but I still hope for this.